# MIT Open course, Lecture 3 - Math problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode

I have a problem regarding the MIT OCW Python Lecture 3.

According to simple math, the code she uses shouldn't be succesful.

```
## EXAMPLE: approximate cube root 
####################
#cube = 27
##cube = 8120601
##cube = 10000
#epsilon = 0.1
#guess = 0.0
#increment = 0.01
#num_guesses = 0
## look for close enough answer and make sure
## didn't accidentally skip the close enough bound
#while abs(guess**3 - cube) >= epsilon and guess <= cube:
#    guess += increment
#    num_guesses += 1
#print('num_guesses =', num_guesses)
#if abs(guess**3 - cube) >= epsilon:
#    print('Failed on cube root of', cube, "with these parameters.")
#else:
#    print(guess, 'is close to the cube root of', cube)
```

This is the code she uses, the problem I'm having is understanding this part:

```
while abs(guess**3 - cube) >= epsilon and guess <= cube:
#    guess += increment
```

If guess is 0.0, cube is 27 and increment is 0.01 then the math by this term should be:

```
abs(0**3 - 27) = 27 #----- This is fine according to the code but the next step would be:#
abs(27.01**3 - 27) = 19677.878101
```

This should stop the loop from working any further. My understanding is obviously wrong somewhere but I can't see where!

Please halp...

Comment: add `print(guess, cube)` after `while`, then check the output (use `cube = 8`), it should clear up the way it works.

Comment: `guess` in the next step is `0.01`, not `27.01`, because you have `guess += increment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Python visualizer to see how the value of guess changes with each iteration. [Try here.](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=cube%20%3D%2027%0A%23cube%20%3D%208120601%0A%23cube%20%3D%2010000%0Aepsilon%20%3D%200.1%0Aguess%20%3D%200.0%0Aincrement%20%3D%200.01%0Anum_guesses%20%3D%200%0A%23%20look%20for%20close%20enough%20answer%20and%20make%20sure%0A%23%20didn't%20accidentally%20skip%20the%20close%20enough%20bound%0Awhile%20abs%28guess**3%20-%20cube%29%20%3E%3D%20epsilon%20and%20guess%20%3C%3D%20cube%3A%0A%20%20%20%20guess%20%2B%3D%20increment%0A%20%20%20%20num_guesses%20%2B%3D%201%0Aprint%28'num_guesses%20%3D',%20num_guesses%29%0Aif%20abs%28guess**3%20-%20cube%29%20%3E%3D%20epsilon%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28'Failed%20on%20cube%20root%20of',%20cube,%20%22with%20these%20parameters.%22%29%0Aelse%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28guess,%20'is%20close%20to%20the%20cube%20root%20of',%20cube%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)